# Change user password while password is empty

Tags: 11.10, password, users

I have a realy strange problem in Ubuntu 11.10. I have by accident my password set to empty. If I wan't to install software now the system asks for a password, but I haven't one anymore. If I enter my old password it sais it's wrong and if I leave it empty it also does. Now I wan't to set my password back, but the system asks for the old password before I can change it. That password doesn't exist, so I can't do anything anymore! Can someone help me please?

Comment: I can't understand why Ubuntu accept an empty password if you can't enter it anywhere...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try running `passwd` from a terminal. It'll ask you for your old password, and then for your new one.
If it doesn't accept the old one there, run `sudo passwd <username>` replacing `<username>` with your username. That will make sure you can change it without the need for your old one, in the hope that it accepts the sudo password.

Comment: when you try sudo passwd then you need to old-password for execution of passwd command (Due to sudo......)

Comment: Not if the password is blank! This is useful trick, thanks RobinJ.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to boot in to recovery mode (press shift key after BIOS post and keep it pressed until the `grub` menu is shown) and drop to a root console. There you will be able to change the password for your current user.

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/reset-lost-administrativeroot-password) you can find a very good example of what to do to reset your password.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My next problem is that I get an authentication error or something like that. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where do you get the fault at? Can you paste the output of the fault, when do you get the fault?

Comment: I get the error when I wrote the password for the second time. I don't have time for trying again so I can't give the whole error now.