# How do I use the command passwd to set a password for user the user01?

Tags: command-line, passwd

Using command line, what do I type to create the password `123xyz` for the user named `user01`?

Comment: Look at the manpage for [`passwd`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/passwd.1.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change user password while password is empty](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78248/change-user-password-while-password-is-empty)

Answer (score 3):

Using

```
apropos password
```

provides an overview on possible command involving password.

In the list, you find:

```
passwd (1)           - change user password
```

This learns you that the command `passwd` can be used to change a password of a user.

Now,

```
man passwd
```

will show you the documentation ("man page") for that command, where you can learn how to change the password of user `user01` to `123xyz`.

Note that you must have administrator (aka "root") privileges to change another user's password. Thus, you will need to precede the `passwd` command with `sudo` in order to execute it with root privileges.